# How to observe a published property via another observable 0bject - Swift Combine

Tags: swiftui, combine

[Edit]

I should point out that I am collecting data from a large number of sensors and having to pollute the view model, that is orchestrating this, with lots of @Published and subscriber code gets quite tedious and error prone.

I've also edited the code to be more representative of the actual problem.

[Original]
I'm trying to reduce the amount of code needed to observer a result from another class when using publishers. I would prefer to publish the result from a class that is generating the result instead of having to propagate it back to the calling class.

Here is a simple playground example showing the issue.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class AnObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var flag: Bool = false

    
    private var timerPub: Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>
    
    private var timerSub: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        
        timerPub = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
        
        
    }
    
    func start() {
        timerSub = timerPub.sink { [self] _ in
            toggleFlag()
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        timerSub?.cancel()
        
    }
    
    func toggleFlag() {
        flag.toggle()
    }
}

class AnotherObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    let ao = AnObservableObject()
    
    func start() {
        ao.start()
    }
   
    func stop() {
        ao.stop()
    }
    
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    @StateObject var ao = AnotherObservableObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if ao.ao.flag {
                Image(systemName: "flag").foregroundColor(.green)
            }
            HStack {
                Button(action: {ao.start()}, label: {
                    Text("Toggle Flag")
                })
                Button(action: {ao.stop()}, label: {
                    Text("Stop")
                })
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
// Make a UIHostingController
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MyView())
// Assign it to the playground's liveView
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
let myView = MyView()
```

The Only way I have got this to work is to do this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class AnObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    
    let flag = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)

    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    
    private var timerPub: Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>
    
    private var timerSub: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        
        timerPub = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
        
        
    }
    
    func start() {
        timerSub = timerPub.sink { [self] _ in
            toggleFlag()
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        timerSub?.cancel()
        
    }
    
    func flagPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        return flag.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func toggleFlag() {
        flag.value.toggle()
    }
}

class AnotherObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    let ao = AnObservableObject()
    
    @Published var flag = false
    
    
    
    init() {


        let flagPublisher = ao.flagPublisher()

        flagPublisher
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$flag)
    }
    
    func start() {
        ao.start()
    }
   
    func stop() {
        ao.stop()
    }
    
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    @StateObject var ao = AnotherObservableObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if ao.flag {
                Image(systemName: "flag").foregroundColor(.green)
            }
            HStack {
                Button(action: {ao.start()}, label: {
                    Text("Toggle Flag")
                })
                Button(action: {ao.stop()}, label: {
                    Text("Stop")
                })
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
// Make a UIHostingController
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MyView())
// Assign it to the playground's liveView
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
let myView = MyView()
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You typically need an `ObservableObject` when you need to use it directly in a view. Why do you need one here? If you didn't, you could have just use a struct instead of `AnObservableObject`

Comment: Hopefully in a couple of weeks. The way you are doing it now is the only way to chain them

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks, let's hope so! Should be an exiting event if SwitftUI, Combine and pro Macs get major updates!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `ObservableObject` for this; you can observe a `Timer` directly in your `View`.

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var flag: Bool = false
    
    @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if flag {
                Image(systemName: "flag").foregroundColor(.green)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {start()}, label: {
                    Text("Toggle Flag")
                })
                Button(action: {stop()}, label: {
                    Text("Stop")
                })
            }
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                flag.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func start() {
        timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've now updated my code, plus provided a hopefully better explanation. Consider collecting location data, manipulating it then passing on a number of results back to the view, I'd like to do this without having to pass these back to the viewModel. And this is just one of the data points I'm collecting.